# Two different ways to calculate the AUC of training set on randomforest give me different results?

Tags: r, random-forest, prediction, auc

I used two ways to calculate the AUC of training set on the randomForest but I get very different results. The two ways are as follows:

```
rfmodel <- randomForest(y~., data=train, importance=TRUE, ntree=1000)
```

Way 1 of calculating AUC of train set:

```
`rf_p_train <- predict(rfmodel, type="prob",newdata = train)[,'yes']  
 rf_pr_train <- prediction(rf_p_train, train$y)  
 r_auc_train[i] <- performance(rf_pr_train, measure = "auc")@y.values[[1]] `
```

Way 2 of calculating AUC of train set:
    `rf_p_train <- as.vector(rfmodel$votes[,2]) 
 rf_pr_train <- prediction(rf_p_train, train$y)
 r_auc_train[i] <- performance(rf_pr_train, measure = "auc")@y.values[[1]]`

Way 1 gives me AUC around 1 but way 2 gives me AUC around 0.65. I am wondering why these two results differ so much. Could anyone help me with this? Really appreciate it. For the data, I am sorry that I am not allowed to share it here. This is the first time for me to ask question here. Please forgive me if there is anything unclear. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. The second way is correct. Why? Because in the first way, you treat `training` data as a new dataset and try to fit it again. In the second way, what you get is actually the so called `out of bag` estimate, and that should be the way to calculate AUC.

Comment: Why the first way will fit the model again? Can you explain more about this?

Comment: say you have dataset and try to perform a linear model. you have a `m1`, and then you put your dataset to this `m1`, and what you can have is exactly the fitted value of the dataset, right?

Comment: Get you! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what data you are using. It is best if you provide a reproducible example but I think I was able to piece one together

```
library(randomForest)
#install.packages("ModelMetrics")
library(ModelMetrics)

# prep training to binary outcome
train <- iris[iris$Species %in% c('virginica', 'versicolor'),]
train$Species <- droplevels(train$Species)

# build model
rfmodel <- randomForest(Species~., data=train, importance=TRUE, ntree=2)

# generate predictions
preds <- predict(rfmodel, type="prob",newdata = train)[,2]

# Calculate AUC
auc(train$Species, preds)

# Calculate LogLoss
logLoss(train$Species, preds)
```

Comment: Thank you! But my problem still hasn't been solved. Could you try calculating the AUC of training data in the following two ways? 1. 'rf_p_train <- predict(rfmodel, type="prob",newdata = train)[,2];
rf_pr_train <- prediction(rf_p_train, train$Species);
r_auc_train[i] <- performance(rf_pr_train, measure = "auc")@y.values[[1]] ' 2. 'rf_p_train <- as.vector(rfmodel$votes[,2]);
rf_pr_train <- prediction(rf_p_train, train$Species);
r_auc_train[i] <- performance(rf_pr_train, measure = "auc")@y.values[[1]]'
They will give us two different AUC and the first one is higher than the second one.

Comment: I am sorry that I am not familiar with how to use stack overflow and really need help on this. Thanks a lot!